# Julia: function types and performance

Tags: performance, julia

Is there a way in Julia to generalise a pattern like the following?

```
function compute_sum(xs::Vector{Float64})
    res = 0
    for i in 1:length(xs)
        res += sqrt(xs[i])
    end
    res
end
```

This computes the square-root of each vector element and then sums everything. It is much faster than the "naive" versions with array comprehension or `map`, and also doesn't allocate additional memory:

```
xs = rand(1000)

julia> @time compute_sum(xs)
  0.000004 seconds
676.8372556762225

julia> @time sum([sqrt(x) for x in xs])
  0.000013 seconds (3 allocations: 7.969 KiB)
676.837255676223

julia> @time sum(map(sqrt, xs))
  0.000013 seconds (3 allocations: 7.969 KiB)
676.837255676223
```

Unfortunately the "obvious" generic version is terrible wrt performance:

```
function compute_sum2(xs::Vector{Float64}, fn::Function)
    res = 0
    for i in 1:length(xs)
        res += fn(xs[i])
    end
    res
end

julia> @time compute_sum2(xs, x -> sqrt(x))
  0.013537 seconds (19.34 k allocations: 1.011 MiB)
676.8372556762225
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that `x -> sqrt(x)` is defined as a new anonymous function with each call to `compute_sum2`, so this causes new compilation every time you call it.

If you define it before even e.g. like this:

```
julia> f = x -> sqrt(x)
```

then you have:

```
julia> @time compute_sum2(xs, f) # here you pay compilation cost
  0.010053 seconds (19.46 k allocations: 1.064 MiB)
665.2469135020949

julia> @time compute_sum2(xs, f) # here you have already compiled everything
  0.000003 seconds (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
665.2469135020949
```

Note that a natural approach would be to define a function with a name like this:

```
julia> g(x) = sqrt(x)
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time compute_sum2(xs, g)
  0.000002 seconds
665.2469135020949
```

You can see that `x -> sqrt(x)` defines a fresh anonymous function each time it is encountered when you write e.g.:

```
julia> typeof(x -> sqrt(x))
var"#3#4"

julia> typeof(x -> sqrt(x))
var"#5#6"

julia> typeof(x -> sqrt(x))
var"#7#8"
```

Note that this would be different if an anonymous function would be defined in a function body:

```
julia> h() = typeof(x -> sqrt(x))
h (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> h()
var"#11#12"

julia> h()
var"#11#12"

julia> h()
var"#11#12"
```

and you see that this time the anonymous function is the same every time.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was due to the unspecific type of `fn` and therefore type instability, but it is indeed the compilation time.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the excellent response by Bogumil, I would just like to add that a very convenient way of generalizing this is to use the normal functional programming function like `map`, `reduce`, `fold`, etc.

In this case, you're doing a `map` transformation (namely `sqrt`) and a reduce (namely `+`), so you can also achieve the result with `mapreduce(sqrt, +, xs)`. This has essentially no overhead and is comparable to a manual loop in performance.

If you have a really complicated series of transformations, you can get optimal performance and still use a function using the Transducers.jl package.

Comment: That is good to know! I actually tried `map` first but was discouraged by the bad performance. Wasn't aware of `mapreduce`.

Answer (score 3):

Bogumił has already answered the part about the function type.  I want to point out that your implementation is already working as efficiently as possible, if [benchmarked properly](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl), but can be replaced by equivalent built-in functions:

```
julia> @btime compute_sum($xs)
  2.149 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
661.6571623823567

julia> @btime sum(sqrt, $xs)
  2.149 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
661.6571623823567

julia> @btime compute_sum2($xs, sqrt)
  2.149 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
661.6571623823567

julia> @btime mapreduce(sqrt, +, $xs)
  2.149 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
661.6571623823567
```

And it is always better to use an eta-equivalent non-lambda function, if possible:  `f` instead of `x -> f(x)`.  Especially for builtin functions, since they are sometimes dispatched on.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are pretty comprehensive, but I wanted to point out that you can just omit the square brackets from `sum([sqrt(x) for x in xs])` and get the fastest version of all:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime compute_sum($xs)
  1.779 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
679.0943275393031

julia> @btime sum([sqrt(x) for x in $xs])
  1.626 μs (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)
679.0943275393028

julia> @btime sum(map(sqrt, $xs))
  1.628 μs (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)
679.0943275393028

julia> @btime sum(sqrt(x) for x in $xs)
  1.337 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
679.0943275393031
```

Also note that on my computer on Julia master `compute_sum` is the slowest, not the fastest way to sum these numbers.

Comment: I would think the generator should not be faster than `sum(sqrt, xs)`, but they should be the same - right?

Comment: True, of course, just including the generator version for completeness: you can get the nice comprehension style without the intermediate allocation.